# Chart.js the point's limit supported

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3

I have a vetor with 50.850 points to plot in the line graph type. I'm using chart.js to show all this points in the graph, but it does not plot. Does anyone know the point's limit the chart.js can show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit to how many points you can have. You should probably split up your data for performance reasons.

[Source](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2010)

Comment: Thanks, I'll split up my data for performance reasons.